Reference request: physics as integrals of the form $\int f(x) e^{g(x)} dx$
Some years ago, I remember reading an expository paper that argued that physics was the study of integrals of the form
$$\int f(x) \ e^{\ g(x)} \ dx \ .$$
In different contexts, these functions $f$ and $g$ take on different meanings, but it’s always the same form.
Regardless, of your thoughts on this characterization, I’d like to find that reference again. I’ve googled around, but I can’t seem to find it!
Given my reading history, it was likely John Baez or Scott Aaronson, but it could have been anyone.
Does anyone know what I’m talking about?

Couldn't you say more succinctly that physics is the study of integrals?

Can't you trivially write any integral $\int dx~h(x)$ in that form by choosing $g(x) = 0$ and $f(x)=h(x)$?

yeah I agree with both of these comments. I’m just trying to find a specific paper I read a few years back.

Another avenue to try is to ask ChatGPT. I don't have any experience with such search myself. Here is how the thought occurred to me: Ben Krasnow (youtube channel: Applied science), used it to try and get unstuck, and ChatGPT surfaced some information that was useful to him.

That's an incredibly vague statement, but I would guess it comes about because they were thinking about the path integral, where the integrand is $e^{i S}$ with possibly a measure factor out front.
